# Oracle sql missing existing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle database. When I run

```
create table test (col1 varchar2(20),
col2 varchar2(20),
col3 varchar2(5),
col4 int(4),
col5 varchar2(20));
```

but I constantly get `00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"` which as you can see it already exists. I would very much appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> col4 int(4)

Remove the size, it should create fine:

```
create table test (col1 varchar2(20),
col2 varchar2(20),
col3 varchar2(5),
col4 int,
col5 varchar2(20));
```

Integer is `ANSI` data type, which is converted to `NUMBER` in Oracle.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213):

> SQL statements that create tables and clusters can also use ANSI data types and data types from the IBM products SQL/DS and DB2. Oracle recognizes the ANSI or IBM data type name that differs from the Oracle Database data type name. **It converts the data type to the equivalent Oracle data type, records the Oracle data type as the name of the column data type, and stores the column data in the Oracle data type based on the conversions shown in the tables that follow**.

```
ANSI SQL Data Type  Oracle Data Type
------------------  ----------------
INTEGER             NUMBER(p,0)
INT 
SMALLINT
```

You could create the table using `NUMBER` with precision of 4:

```
create table test (col1 varchar2(20),
col2 varchar2(20),
col3 varchar2(5),
col4 number(4), --> Using Oracle NUMBER data type with precision 4
col5 varchar2(20));
```